# Cocos2d - Tile Map Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Whenever I add my tilemap to my Cocos2d project, I either receive an error or with luck at least achieve a blackscreen without the app crashing. The error that Xcode is returning is:

```
rect.origin.x = (gid % max_x) * (tileSize_.width + spacing_) + margin_;
```

The Log returns

```
2012-07-30 22:40:29.237 Tile Map Game[8233:c07] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:Xcode/Game Development/Tilesets/Desert_Tileset.png in CCTextureCache
```

And last but not least is my code

```
-(id) init
 {
     if( (self=[super init] )) {

         self.tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"DesertMap.tmx"];
         self.backgroundLayer = [tileMap layerNamed:@"Background"];

         [self addChild:tileMap z:-1];

      }
     return self;
 }

 - (void) dealloc {

     self.tileMap = nil;
     self.backgroundLayer = nil;

     [super dealloc];
 }
```

What's going on here? I've tried so many tileset preferences such as the margin spacing from 0 to 1 still with no luck though.

Answer (score 1):

The image saved in your TMX file uses a relative path:

```
Xcode/Game Development/Tilesets/Desert_Tileset.png
```

This path does not normally exist in your iOS project because app bundles flatten all folders so that all files are in the same path in the app bundle.

You should place your tileset files in the same folder as the TMX file both when editing and when adding them to your project.

In this case you may have to remove and re-add the tileset in Tiled, or simply edit the TMX file (close it in Tiled before doing so) and remove the path to the tileset. Especially if you have already added properties to the tileset this will be the easier option as you won't have to re-edit the tileset (tile) properties.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Desert_Tileset.png image into your resources. I solved my error like this.